# How to calculate the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{b+2bn}{a}\right)^{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

First of all consider

> \begin{align}
> \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}dx & = \int_{0}^{\infty}2\frac{\sin(ax)}{e^{bx}-e^{-bx}} \\
> & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)e^{-bx}}{1-e^{-2bx}} \\
> & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(ax)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(bx+2bnx)} \\
> & = 2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(ax)e^{-x(b+2bn)} dx \\
> & = 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a}{a^{2}+(b+2bn)^{2}} \\
> & = \frac{2}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{b+2bn}{a}\right)^{2}}.
> \end{align}

Now, how can we calculate this sum? My teacher said me about Poisson's method? But I haven't seen it yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Weierstrass product of hyperbolic cosine function
$$\cosh x=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\dfrac{4x^2}{\pi^2(2n-1)^2}\right)$$
and differentiate of $\ln\cosh x$ then find
$$\tanh x=2x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^2+\frac14(2n-1)^2\pi^2}$$
Now let $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{a}{b}$.

Comment: It looks nice, but it help us if we know the answer. It's harder to get it.

Comment: Here is the same as you've done! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543862/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-dfrac-sinx-sinhx-dx/2543930#2543930

Comment: @MyGlasses (+1) for this approach.

Answer (score 9):

> **Herein, we present an approach that uses contour integration.  To that end we now proceed.**

---

Without loss of generality, we will assume that $a>0$ and $b>0$.

---

First, note that the integral of interest can be written

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}\,dx=\frac12\text{Im}\left(\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iaz}}{\sinh(bz)}\,dz\right)$$

where $\text{PV}$ denotes the Cauchy Principal Value.

---

Next, we analyze the contour integral $\displaystyle \oint_C \frac{e^{iaz}}{\sinh(bz)}\,dz$, where $C$ is the contour comprised of $(1)$ the real line segment from $-(N+1/2)\frac\pi b$ to $-\epsilon$, $(2)$ the semi-circular arc $z=\epsilon e^{i\phi}$, $\phi\in[-\pi,0]$, $(3)$ the real line segment from $\epsilon$ to $(N+1/2)\frac\pi b$, and $(4)$ the semi-circular arc $z=(N+1/2)\frac\pi b e^{i\phi}$, $\phi\in[0,\pi]$.

Using the residue theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{e^{iaz}}{\sinh(bz)}\,dz&=2\pi i \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1b(-1)^n e^{-n\pi b/a}\right)\\\\
&=-2\pi i \left(\frac1b\,\frac{e^{-\pi a/b}}{1+e^{-\pi a/b}}\right)
\end{align}$$

As $N\to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{e^{iax}}{\sinh(bx)}\,dx&=i\frac{\pi}{b}\left(1-2\frac{e^{-\pi a/b}}{1+e^{-\pi a/b}}\right)\\\\
&=i\frac{\pi}{b}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{\pi a}{2b}\right)\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Taking the imaginary part of $(1)$ and dividing by $(2)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}\,dx=\frac{\pi }{2b}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi a}{2b}\right)}$$

Comment: @MyGlasses Thank you!  Much appreciated.