# Compute the integral with use of complex analysis techniques

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Compute the integral: $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{x^2 + 2x\cos\lambda+1}dx, (-1 < p < 1, -\pi < \lambda < \pi)$$ with complex analysis techinques.
What I've tried in this problem (because the problem is located among other problems that I've solved using the $\textit{circle that avoids positive part of x-axes}$) is to find residues in the singularities and that would give me solution. But, in case of $0 < p < 1$ this integral does not have same properties as in case $- 1 < p < 0$ (we had classified them as separate types), so I am clueless here. Any help is appreciated. Should I use any particular curve that is non-standard, or I am missing something? Thank you.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Also, it is clear to me that the $p$ is chosen in such way that the integral converges.

Comment: See this answer from this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/890358/349501

Comment: What you  also can do is to consider the same integral but with $(-x) ^p$ and do the integration on a dog bone contour with the "bone" on the positive real axis. Use the Principal Log for that.

Comment: It might be worth to have a look at the following answer for the latter suggestion. The exponent is imaginary but the technique remains the same. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529614/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracx-mathfrakiax2bx1-mathrm/2529805#2529805

Comment: @Shashi that is idea and contour I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis)

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^p}{x^2+2x\cos\lambda+1}=\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{\sin\lambda}\int_{0}^{+\infty}s^{-p-1}e^{-s\cos\lambda}\sin(s\sin\lambda)\,ds $$
and by the integral representation for the $\Gamma$ function and the reflection formula the RHS equals
$$ \frac{-\Gamma(p+1)\,\Gamma(-p)\sin(p\lambda)}{\sin\lambda}=\frac{\pi\sin(p\lambda)}{\sin(\lambda)\sin(\pi p)}.$$

Comment: Is there any other way to solve it? We haven't done Laplace transforms during any of analysis courses.

Comment: The same can be achieved by contour integration, once a suitable contour has been found. The main reasons I prefer to use the Laplace transform when possible is due to its simplicity and the fact that, like Feyman's trick, it allows to skip *the hunt for the right contour*. So, even if you have not met it during your courses, it is definitely worth studying.