# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-p}}{x^2+2x\cos\theta +1}\,dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have to show that:

$$  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-p}}{x^2+2x\cos\theta +1}\,dx = \frac{\pi \sin (p\theta)}{\sin (p\pi) \sin(\theta)}$$

for $0<p<1$ and $0 < \theta < \pi$.

We can write the denominator as $(x+e^{i\theta})(x+e^{-i\theta})$ and I now want to evaluate this integral using contour integration. However, I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: Have you tried $x=e^u$?

Comment: As one of the two sides of the "keyhole" in the Hankel contour?

Comment: Duplicate of [Symmetry of function defined by integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268789/symmetry-of-function-defined-by-integral), or maybe it was better to mark it as a duplicate of this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/890210/515527).